# Find volume bounded by 3 equations using integration

Tags: integration, analysis, volume

The prompt is to find the volume of the solid bounded by the equations $x^2 + y^2 -2y = 0$, $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z \ge 0$

Plotting the equations, I get something like this

[image]

We get a paraboloid and a cylinder.

How to know if I have to use double or triple integration to solve this problem? and if I should use spherical or double polar or cylindrical coordinate system?
Also how to find the limits of integration in this particular problem as an example?

This is what the cross section looks like [image]

It is clearly visible that $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$

Comment: is the region even closed...?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "closed"

Comment: You have to calculate the volume (triple integral using $1$ as your function of integration) over the part of the cylinder bounded by the $xy$-plane and the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$. And cylindrical coordinates appear to be the easiest. Doing a double integral will also work, with the function of integration being $z=x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Second method}$ (I presume that this is the method you want):

Show that the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$, the $xy$-plane $z=0$, and the cylinder $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

This time, use the change of coordinates: 
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= r\cos \theta, \\ 
y &=r\sin\theta, \\ 
z &=z, \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
where 
$$
\begin{align*}
0 \leq &z\leq r^2, \\ 
0\leq &r \leq 2\sin\theta, \mbox{ and }\\ 
0 \leq &\theta \leq \pi. \\ 
\end{align*}
$$

Let $E$ be the solid defined in this prompt. 
Then the volume of the enclosed object is 
$$
\begin{align*}
V&=\iiint_E 1 \: dV \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta} \int_{0}^{r^2} r\: dzdrd\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta} r^3 \: dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{r^4}{4}\Bigg|_0^{2\sin\theta} \: d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} 4\sin^4\theta\: d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} 4\left( \frac{1-\cos(2\theta) }{2}\right)^2 \: d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( 1-\cos(2\theta) \right)^2 \: d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( 1-2\cos(2\theta)+\cos^2(2\theta) \right) \: d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( 1-2\cos(2\theta)+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(4\theta) \right) \: d\theta \\ 
&=  \theta +\sin(2\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\theta +\frac{1}{8}\sin(4\theta) \Bigg|_0^{\pi} \\ 
&=\frac{3}{2}\pi + 0 + 0 \\ 
&=\frac{3}{2}\pi. 
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First, complete the square to see that 
$$
x^2+y^2-2y=x^2 +(y-1)^2-1=0. 
$$
So $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$. The cylindrical change-of-coordinate we will be using is: 
$$
x=r\cos \theta, \hspace{4mm} y=1+r\sin \theta,\hspace{4mm}   z=z, \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ where } 0\leq r\leq 1,\hspace{4mm}  0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi. 
$$
Note that the absolute value of the Jacobian is:
$$
\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}\right| 
= \left| \pmatrix{
x_r& x_\theta \\
y_r & y_\theta \\ 
}
\right| 
 = r. 
$$
Now, we calculate the volume of the solid: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\iint_{D} \int_0^{x^2+y^2} dz\: dA 
&= \iint_{D} x^2+y^2 \: dA \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left( (r\cos\theta)^2 + (1+r\sin \theta)^2  \right) 
r\: dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left( r^2\cos^2\theta+ r^2\sin^2 \theta + 1+2 r\sin \theta  \right) 
r\: dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left( r^2 + 1+2 r\sin \theta  \right) 
r\: dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left( r^3 + r + 2 r^2 \sin \theta  \right) 
  dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \frac{r^4}{4} + \frac{r^2}{2} + 2 \frac{r^3}{3} \sin \theta  \right) \Bigg|_{0}^1 
 d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} \sin \theta  \right)  
 d\theta \\ 
&= \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi -\frac{2}{3}\cos\theta\Bigg|_{0}^{2\pi} \\
&= \frac{3\pi}{2}. 
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why is $y = 1 + r\sin\theta$ ?

Comment: Since $z \ge 0$ shouldn't the limit for $\theta$ be from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: @Ritwick To answer your first question, we see that the cylinder of radius $1$ has rotational symmetry about the points $(0,1 ,z)$, where $z$ is a real number.

Comment: @Ritwick It is correct as it stands. The range for $\theta$ should be from $0$ to $2\pi$ because under the cylindrical change-of-coordinates given above, the axis of rotation has been shifted so that it is passing through $(0,1,0)$ and is parallel to the $z$-axis. Let's call this axis of rotation $\ell$. Then $r\geq0$ is the horizontal distance from $\ell$ and $\theta$ is the angle (measured along a horizontal plane) from the reference direction (which is parallel to the $+x$-axis whose reference point is on $\ell$ and on a horizontal plane) to another point on the same horizontal plane.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Third method}$: find the volume of the cylinder, where $0\leq z\leq 4$, and then subtract from it the volume of the cylinder whose lower bound is the paraboloid and upper bound is the plane $z=4$.

So rather than working with the equations: 
$$
\color{blue}{z=0, \hspace{4mm} z=x^2+y^2, \hspace{4mm}  \mbox{ and } \hspace{4mm} x^2+(y-1)^2=1,} 
$$
imagine picking up the solid and then moving it so that the axis of rotation for the cylinder $\underline{\textbf{is}}$ the $z$-axis. This solid is now bounded by the equations:
$$
\color{green}{z=0, \hspace{4mm} z=x^2+(y+1)^2, \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ and } \hspace{4mm} x^2+y^2=1,} 
$$
which has been plotted below: 
[image: solid-coord-axes-shifted]

The volume of the cylinder is given by
$$
\text{Volume}(\text{cylinder}) = \pi R^2 h = \pi 1^2(4) = 4\pi. 
$$
The volume of the cylinder $E'$ whose lower bound is the paraboloid and upper bound is the plane $z=4$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Volume}(E') 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta+1)^2}^{4}r\: dz dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}
4r-\left( r^3\cos^2\theta + r(r\sin\theta+1)^2\right) \: dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}
\left( 3 r - r^3 (\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta )- 2 r^2 \sin\theta \right) \: dr d\theta \\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}
\left( 3 r - r^3 - 2 r^2 \sin\theta \right) \: dr d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} 
\left( \frac{3}{2} r^2 - \frac{1}{4}r^4 - \frac{2}{3} r^3 \sin\theta \right) \Bigg|_0^1 \:   d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} 
\left( \frac{5}{4}    - \frac{2}{3}  \sin\theta \right)  \:   d\theta \\ 
&=  \frac{5}{4}\theta +\frac{2}{3}  \cos\theta\Bigg|_0^{2\pi} \\ 
&= \frac{5}{2}\pi. 
\end{align*}
$$
Thus 
$$
\text{Volume}(\text{solid}) = 4\pi - \frac{5}{2}\pi = \boxed{\frac{3}{2}\pi}. 
$$